# Errores al convertir un proyecto a maven

Tags: java, java-ee, maven, websphere

Estoy trabajando con html, javascript, struts1, oracle11, jQuery, spring, tiles, etc... Y tengo el siguiente problema.

Intentando convertirlo a proyecto maven de forma automática con eclipse me lanza el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Exactamente el error en el pom.xml me da en la siguiente línea que os muestro en la imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si os sirve de ayuda también os pongo la información sobre dicho error en la línea que observáis con el error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

Si necesitáis algo más de información al respecto no dudéis en preguntarlo, muchas gracias de antemano.

Añado también los errores que saca la consola al poner mvn -U:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Trabajas bajo un proxy?

Comment: Si @pablo pero en el eclipse lo tengo configurado

Comment: Prueba a configurarlo también para maven, que tiene pinta de venir por ahí el error. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: Gracias @pablo ya que no lo tenía configurado, pero me sigue dando el mismo error :(

Comment: Prueba con `mvn -U` o con 
`alt + f5` y dándole a  "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases". podría resultar

Comment: Hola @MaQuiNa1995 ya había intentado lo de actualizar el proyecto desde la opción que comentas, pero no había marcado la casilla de "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases". Lo acabo de hacer pero me sigue mostrando el mismo error. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Has probado a abrirlo desde otro IDE ? a ver si te da el mismo fallo? Podría ser un fallo aleatorio de Eclipse

Comment: @MaQuiNa1995 Probé lo del  mvn -U y me salían tmb errores. Los publico si queréis en la pregunta

Comment: Si, añádeles a ver si encontramos el problema, o conseguimos mas información

Comment: Elimina todo tu .m2 y vuelve a generar el proyecto con `mvn clean package  -U`

Comment: Creo que para el primer problema ya tienes la solución: `mvn -U` o `Alt+F5`. En cuanto al mensaje de `No goals have been specified for this build ...` es debido a que cuando ejecutas Maven debes decirle **para qué**. Ejemplo: `mvn install`, o `mvn compile`  o `mvn deploy`. Para más detalles [ver la doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Gracias chicos, voy a echarle un ojo a ver y ahora os comento ;)

Comment: Ahora el error que me lanza es "The goal you specified a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\jgtardio). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory" Pero si que lo tengo ahí el repositorio local que es donde direcciono...

Comment: tienes que hacer lo del comando del mvn que te dije en el carpeta del proyecto, recuerda borrar la carpeta del .m2 y despues ir a donde tengas el proyecto (ruta) y hacer el comando

Comment: Muchas gracias, finalmente he conseguido limpiar casi todos los errores, me aparece uno que creo que es por las dependencias, ahora lo pongo en comentario por si tenéis alguna idea, entre todos y por internet he conseguido al menos que arranca jaja muchas gracias a todos chicos :)

Comment: Este es e lque me da ahora justo en la primera línea del pom.xml: "Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of 
 central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Unexpected status 
 line: 465"